# Создание массива из 8 символов и заполнение его рандомными числами в диапазоне от -10 до 10

Tags: c++, c, массивы, случайные-числа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h> 



void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int const SIZE = 8;
    int arr[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 0 + 10;

        count << arr[i] << endl;
     }     
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
arr[i] = rand() % 0 + 10;
```

Смеяться над нами хотите? :) Делить на ноль?

```
arr[i] = -10 + rand() % 21;
```

И будет у вас от 10 до +10 включительно...

Comment: Всё равно ему #define'а не хватит)))

Comment: Не вижу ни комментария от минусатора, ни его более верного ответа...

Comment: Я наоборот плюс ставил.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да я не к тебе :) Просто, как по мне, если уж минус ставишь - то надо хотя бы объяснить, почему. Минус - значит, в ответе что-то не так. Мы не святые, бывают ошибки, опечатки и т.д. - ну так укажи ее, что ж оставлять неверный ответ, который будет вводить в заблуждение? Или дай хотя бы свой верный..